# prevent paper-listbox selection change

Tags: polymer-2.x

I got a paper-listbox containing a paper-checkbox contained within each paper-item of the list.

```
<paper-listbox id="groupMembers" multi attr-for-selected="label">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[users]]" as="member">
        <paper-item label="[[member.user]]">
            <span class="member-user">[[member.user]]</span>
            <paper-checkbox checked="[[member.isManager]]"></paper-checkbox>
        </paper-item>
    </template>
</paper-listbox>
```

Whenever the checkbox is clicked it also changes the selected state of the listbox items resulting in an paper-item becoming selected or deselected.

How can that be prevented?

Answer (score 1):

`paper-listbox` uses `Polymer.IronSelectableBehavior` and `Polymer.IronMultiSelectableBehavior`. So, you can use `selectable` attribute in order to prevent changing the selected state.

`selectable` is a CSS selector string. If this is set, only items that match the CSS selector are selectable. You can put a random string so that it won't match the `paper-item` element.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/zwwiTbUNk9qfpMUOhJvw?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that doesn't solve my problem. The paper-items must be selectable but the selected state of an paper-item must not change by the click on the checkbox within that item. Possbile at all?

Comment: @JoernTurner That was not mentioned in you question.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by avoiding it ;)

Moved the checkbox out of the paper-item into the dom-repeat like so:

```
<paper-listbox id="groupMembers" multi attr-for-selected="label">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[users]]" as="member">
        <paper-item label="[[member.user]]">
            <span class="member-user">[[member.user]]</span>
        </paper-item>
        <div class="checkWrapper">
            <paper-checkbox checked="[[member.isManager]]"></paper-checkbox>
        </div>
    </template>
</paper-listbox>
```

With a bit of CSS positioning magic that works. Added a wrapper div to allow absolute positioning.